# Configuring cluster rabbitMQ on EC2 - nodes provided are either offline or not running Error

Tags: amazon-ec2, erlang, rabbitmq, cluster-computing

I followed closely the rabbitmq clustering documentation on the site but failed for a full day to generate a cluster on EC2.
I frequently got

```
The nodes provided are either offline or not running
```

(Though I had a telnet and my cookie was the same).

Eventually I solved it by recording the TCP communication (upon join_cluster command) and reading it )

I saw that after the triple handshake when the first node connects to the second,
a packet contains a new port is transferred

[image]

So, I really don't know what it is but I tried to open it in my security group
(The firewall is down anyhow, but I need to update the port in EC2 Security Group)
and finally after a lot of trials it worked.

My questions :
1. What is this port.
2. Is it a random port? How do I set it so I can control it?
3. Was I missing it in the [clustering guide](https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html)? It is kinda important. I couldnt find any   document related to the rabbitmq clustering and this port.

4. I did find some stuff regarding [clustering erlang](http://www.erlang.org/faq/how_do_i.html#id55090). and it mentioned setting inet_dist_listen_min and inet_dist_listen_max. Is this it?
5. I need to set  it using

   application:set_env(kernel, inet_dist_listen_min, 9100).
   application:set_env(kernel, inet_dist_listen_max, 9105).

How do I run configure this lines? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Finally - I found the way to create and configure RABBITMQ Cluster with mirrored queues.

Via AWS - Create a Security Group: test-rabbit
The open ports are:
4369,5672,15672,25672,55672
And...
All TCP Ports (0-65535) Custom IP test-rabbit
(meaning that between the nodes all tcp ports are opened)

The last one was the key to all problem I had.
We noticed that there are various ports that are opened that are not written in any rabbitmq documention and they were different on different machines, opening all TCP traffic betweeen the nodes that are using this security group - solved anything.

Don't forget to make sure the earlang cookie is exactly the same between all nodes and to REBOOT the machines after changing the cookie.

Comment: how to open all TCP traffic?

Comment: In AWS, when you create a security group, you than can define/configure the protocols and ports

Comment: I got that, but I mean that you select TCP port range from 0 to max?

Comment: One option is to open all 65K ports, just to figure out if this was the issue and continue from there.